# pandas groupby and droplevel changes series name

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':[1,22.2,3.4,4.2,55.4,6.3], 
                   'dates':['2019-10-01','2019-10-01','2019-10-01','2019-10-02','2019-10-02','2019-10-02'],
                   'names':['name1','name2','name3','name1','name2','name3']})
df = df.set_index(['dates','names']).squeeze()
```

I am looking at using `.groupby` and `.apply`, but I am confused as to what is happening.

If I am trying to apply the function:

```
def my_func(data):
    return data.to_frame()
```

using:

```
df.groupby('dates').apply(my_func)
```

I get the following output:

```
                  2019-10-01  2019-10-02
dates      names                        
2019-10-01 name1         1.0         NaN
           name2        22.2         NaN
           name3         3.4         NaN
2019-10-02 name1         NaN         4.2
           name2         NaN        55.4
           name3         NaN         6.3
```

Why is `df.name` is replaced with the groupby variable name after using `droplevel`?

Comment: what are you trying to do? here for each date you create a df

Comment: Within `my_func` I am ultimately trying to merge `data` with another dataframe `t` with similar indices into `merged`.  Then I would expect `merged['values']` to return the same as `data.values`.  `merged['values']` throws an error because the `data.name` is not passed to the data frame.  I have simplified my post to illustrate my question and not get a bunch of recommendations on how to merge dataframes.

Comment: What dataframe are you trying to merge with? Can you provide the full code where the merge is an issue. The groupby actually creates a dataframe with two series in it. A dataframe does not have a `.name` attribute, the two `Series` which make up the dataframe do have names corresponding to their column names, so `merged['2019-10-01'].name == '2019-10-01'`

Comment: The question is not about merging Dataframes.  It’s about how groupby results in a dataframe with column names that match a particular groups name.